# Using dynamic arrays to store large integers

Tags: c++, arrays

Instructions are:

The largest value   that    an  int variable    can handle  is  2147483647. Make a class
called largeInteger that uses a dynamic array to store an integer of any amount of
digits.
    provide an input() function to take the input of a large integer from cin.
    provide an print() function to display a large integer to cout.
    provide an add() function to add two large integers and return the sum as a
    large integer

So far, I've had issues with inputting and passing values between functions, as my grasp of c++ syntax is awfully limited. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Here is my current code, riddled with problems.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class largeInteger {
  public:
         // Takes input of a large integer from cin
         largeInteger = input();
         // displays large integer to cout
         void print(int largeInteger);
         // adds two large integers and returns the sum as a large integer
         void add();
};

int * input () {
 int * input;
 input = new int;
 cout << "Please enter a large integer: ";
 cin >> input;
 return input;
}

void print (largeInteger) {
 cout << "The entered large integer is: " << largeInteger;
}

void add (largeInteger) {
 int * sum;
 sum = new int;
 sum = largeInteger + largeInteger;
 cout << "The sum of the two large integers is: " << largeInteger;
 delete sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int * largeInteger;
largeInteger = new int;
system("PAUSE");
delete largeInteger;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's almost everything wrong with this code. Almost all of this it is not valid C++. It's great that you made effort yourself but there's a long road ahead of you - so just pick up a book and learn how C++ works. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can see many problems with the code. Let's start with your input function.

```
int * input () { // This line needs to be changed
  int * input; // This is fine too
  input = new int; // error here
  cout << "Please enter a large integer: "; // This is fine
  cin >> input; // This won't work
  return input;
}
```

To declare a dynamic array you need to specify the size of the array. You do not specify a size. Also, you need to figure out what size of array do you need (how many numbers need to be in the largeInteger). For that, you need to know how big the user inputed number is. So you need to allocate the dynamic array after getting the user input and finding out how big it is.

I would suggest you use a string to get the user input, that way you can get the size of the input. Also, to simplify things, we'll need to create and return the largeInteger in the function.

Here's the corrected code so far:

```
largeInteger input () {
  int * input; // This is fine too
  cout << "Please enter a large integer: "; // This is fine
  string userInput; // Don't forget to add #include <string>
  cin >> userInput;
  input = new int[userInput.length()]
  return input;
}
```

userInput.length() calls the length function of a string object which returns the size of the string. Now we have to go through every character in the string and convert them to integers to add them to the input dynamic array.

We can use a for-loop to do that. Let's also create the largeInteger at the same time. We'll also need to take the input backwards, because it will be easier later. So the corrected input function is:

```
largeInteger input () {
  int * input; // This is fine
  cout << "Please enter a large integer: "; // This is fine too
  string userInput; // Don't forget to add #include <string>
  cin >> userInput;
  input = new int[userInput.length()]
  for(int i = userInput.length()-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
  {
    int intValue = userInput[i] - '0'; // This converts the char inside the string to an int
    input[i] = intValue;
  }
  largeInteger big = largeInteger(input, userInput.length()); // This line only makes sense with the changes detailed later in the post.
  return input;
}
```

Ok, now that part is done, time to move on to the class definition.

```
class largeInteger {
  public:             
         largeInteger = input(); // error here

         void print(int largeInteger); // needs to be redeclared

         void add(); // Needs to be redeclared
};
```

I've removed your comments for clarity purposes. So, the way you create an object of a certain class is through it's constructor, so let's add that in and remove

```
largeInteger = input();
```

A constructor has the same name as the class and is a function. A class also contains both data and functions, so we will need to add a data member to contain the dynamic array. We also want our constructor to take a dynamic array as function so it can initialize it's data member. We'll also need the size of the dynamic array for some of the later functions, so we'll add that as a data member too. Here's how the corrected class definition looks right now:

```
class largeInteger {
  public:             
         largeInteger(int* array, int newSize){
           dataMember = array;
           size = newSize;
         }

         void print(int largeInteger); // needs to be redeclared            
         void add(); // Needs to be redeclared            
         int* dataMember; // The new data member that we added
         int size;
};
```

Now let's work on the print function. The print function doesn't need any parameter because it can access the data member. The way we are going to print the data member through the same way we created it, through a for-loop. You can define a method (another name for a function in a class) outside the class definition, but you need to say where it's from here's how you write that:

```
void largeInteger::print(){
  for(int i = size; i >=0; i--){ // Remember, we need to print it backwards of backwards, so forwards
    cout << dataMember[i]; 
  }
}
```

Here, size and dataMember both are data members from the class we declared above. We can access them because we declare print as a method of largeInteger.

Let's now look at the add function.

We need to declare it so that it takes another largeInteger as parameter, otherwise it won't add anything with anything else. It also needs to return a largeInteger, otherwise adding them up won't do anything. So let's rewrite it to write the final version of the largeInterger class definition.

```
class largeInteger {
  public:             
         largeInteger(int* array, int newSize){
           dataMember = array;
           size = newSize;
         }

         void print(int largeInteger); // needs to be redeclared            
         largeInteger add(largeInteger rhs); // rhs means right-hand-side           
         int* dataMember; // The new data member that we added
         int size;
};
```

Let's look at it's implementation. This is the most complicated function, but it is possible. We need to add the numbers one-by-one, and we need to add the carryover to the next number.  Also, since we got the numbers backwards, it's easier to add them up. Here's one implementation:

```
largeInteger largeInteger::add(largeInteger rhs){
  int* sum;
  if (size >= rhs.size){
    sum = new int[size+1]; // size+1 is the maximum size the large int could get in this situation
    int carryover = 0;
    // Add the two numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.size; i++){
        int partialSum = dataMember[i] + rhs.dataMember[i] + carryover;
        if( partialSum >= 10){
          carryover = 1;
          partialSum -= 10;
        }
        else{
          carryover = 0;
        }
        sum[rhs.size - i - 1] = partialSum; // remember, we have to enter the numbers backwards
      }
    // Fill in the remaining numbers
    for(int i = size-1; i >= rhs.size; i--){
      sum[i] = dataMember[i];
    }
    return largeInteger(sum,size+1);
  }
  else{
    sum = new int[rhs.size+1]; // rhs.size+1 is the maximum size the large int could get in this situation
    int carryover = 0;
    // Add the two numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int partialSum = dataMember[i] + rhs.dataMember[i] + carryover;
        if( partialSum >= 10){
          carryover = 1;
          partialSum -= 10;
        }
        else{
          carryover = 0;
        }
        sum[size - i - 1] = partialSum; // remember, we have to enter the numbers backwards
      }
    // Fill in the remaining numbers
    for(int i = rhs.size-1; i >= size; i--){
      sum[i] = rhs.dataMember[i];
    }
    return largeInteger(sum,rhs.size+1);
  }

}
```

Now that I reread the code, this might've been done without keeping the numbers stored backwards internally, but I don't feel like changing it. So here you go.

But yeah, like others have said, you really should read a C++ book because basically none of what you wrote is valid C++, or really does what you want it to.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! This is my second c++ class, the first one I did much better in, but never covered dynamic arrays. I went through several iterations based on what I could google, but the professor isn't big on covering anything we're actually going to use for some reason. I'll try to keep at it, though!